# Uniroot solution two equatations

Tags: r, function, uniroot

I posted similar question a few days later, but now I have more complex problem.
I have this dataset

```
product = data.frame(length = c(100, 200, 300, 400), qty = c(1, 2, 1, 3))
```

And price is defined by this equation `(product[["length"]] * old_const * 2) + setup_price` where `old_const = 0.0158` and `setup_price = 20.8`

```
product[["old_price"]] = (product[["length"]] * old_const * 2) + setup_price
```

Now I would like to change constant `setup_price` to meet two requirements:

Total revenue with new prices is same as revenue with old prices AND
Total revenue from first half of table is same as revenue from second half of table

```
y1 = sum((product[["length"]] * old_const * 2  + setup_price)* product[["qty"]])
y2 = sum((product[["length"]] * 2)* product[["qty"]])
y3 = sum((product[1:table_median, ][["length"]] * 2)* product[1:table_median, ][["qty"]])
y4 = sum((product[table_median:max(nrow(product)), ][["length"]] * 2) * product[table_median:max(nrow(product)), ][["qty"]])

where table_median = round(median(1:nrow(product)))
```

And my optimalization

```
const = seq(-2,2, by = 0.0001)
ev = NULL

for (i in 1:length(const)){
  ev[i] = (y1 - y2 * const[i]) + (y3*const[i] - y4)
}

plot(const, ev)
```

And I would like to get `ev = 0` nad I dont know where exactly my 0 is.

There was recomandation to use `uniroot` function which I know how to use with one equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change belt_length to length to make sense of what you shared.
I've gone ahead and simply refactored your for loop to involve a function, and then use that same function in uniroot

```
const = seq(-2,2, by = 0.0001)
ev = NULL

custfunc <- function(x){
  (y1 - y2 * x) + (y3*x - y4)
}
for (i in 1:length(const)){
  ev[i] = custfunc(const[i])
}

plot(const, ev)

uniroot(custfunc,interval = c(-2,2))
```